# generate date out of multiple columns

Tags: sql, postgresql, date

I have a (Postgre)SQL table in which dates are stored like this

```
YEAR    B-MONTH    E-MONTH
2000      01         05
2004      03         06
2010      07         12
2004      01         12
```

How can I turn these to "real" date fields? I'd like the output to look like this:

```
  BEGIN          END
2000-01-01    2000-05-31
2004-03-01    2004-06-30
2010-07-01    2010-12-31
2004-01-01    2004-12-31
```

Thank you in advance!

**[solution]**

This is the solution I ended up with:

*begin*

```
TO_DATE(TO_CHAR("YEAR", '9999') || TO_CHAR("B-MONTH", 'FM00') || '01', 'YYYYMMDD') AS BEGIN
```

*end*

```
CAST(TO_DATE(TO_CHAR("YEAR", '9999') || TO_CHAR("E-MONTH", 'FM00') || '01', 'YYYYMMDD') + INTERVAL ('1 MONTH - 1 DAY') AS DATE) AS END
```

**[edit]**

It also works like that:

*begin*

```
TO_DATE(TO_CHAR("YEAR", '9999') || TO_CHAR("B-MONTH", 'FM00'), 'YYYYMM') AS BEGIN
```

*end*

```
CAST(TO_DATE(TO_CHAR("YEAR", '9999') || TO_CHAR("E-MONTH", 'FM00'), 'YYYYMM') + INTERVAL ('1 MONTH - 1 DAY') AS DATE) AS END
```

Comment: Please post the code you have written so far. People generally do not like to just write your code for you. As it is, this is a work description, not a question.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion. I don't really know how to start as I don't know a function that turns integer values into date parts. But please don't read my question like I want you to code the whole thing for me. If somebody points me the way to a helpful function I would be very glad.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

you need first to convert your integer values into char then into date, example :

```
to_date(to_char(b_month, '00') || to_char(YEAR,'9999'), 'MMYYYY') as START_DATE
```

for the second column which returns date end, not sure for POSTGRESQL if there is an existing function to return the last day of the month as the ORACLE function `LAST_DAY`, so here is an example under Oracle :

```
last_day(to_date(to_char(e_month, '00') || to_char(YEAR,'9999'), 'MMYYYY')) as END_DATE
```

Comment: thank you! `LAST_DAY` is not implemented in PostGreSQL, but one can help herself by adding one month and subtracting one day (see http://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Date_LastDay) thank you once more!